# Nuvem de palavras Shiny R

Tags: r, wordcloud, shiny

Eu estou querendo fazer um nuvem de palavras usando dados de uma tabela do postgresql. Eu usei um exemplo como base que achei no site do Shiny R, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o que quero.

Não consigo mudar qual a variável que vai servir como base da nuvem de palavras. Precisava que ao mudar o nome na seleção no "selectinput" a nuvem também deveria mudar a variável que é usada.

```
Server.R

function(input, output, session) {
# Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix
terms <- reactive({
# Change when the "update" button is pressed...
input$update
# ...but not for anything else
isolate({
  withProgress({
    setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
    getTermMatrix(input$selection)
  })
})
})

# Make the wordcloud drawing predictable during a session
wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

output$plot <- renderPlot({
v <- terms()
wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
              min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
              colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
})
}

Ui.R
fluidPage(
# Application title
titlePanel("Word Cloud"),

sidebarLayout(
# Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("selection", "Choose a book:",
              choices = c("Forzza","Viana")),
  actionButton("update", "Change"),
  hr(),
  sliderInput("freq",
              "Minimum Frequency:",
              min = 1,  max = 1000, value = 1),
  sliderInput("max",
              "Maximum Number of Words:",
              min = 1,  max = 100,  value = 100)
),

# Show Word Cloud
mainPanel(
 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
     tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))

)
)
)
)

Global.r
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)

library(RPostgreSQL)
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user="postgres",  password="123456",dbname="postgres")
coletor1=dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT REPLACE(aux_coletprinc,' ','')  aux_coletprinc  from jabot.detacesso2 where aux_coletprinc ilike '%forz%a%'
 limit 10")
coletor2=dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT REPLACE(aux_coletprinc,' ','')    aux_coletprinc  from jabot.detacesso2 where aux_coletprinc ilike '%vian%a%'
 limit 10")

dbDisconnect(con)

books <<- list("Forzza" ,
          "Viana" )


# Using "memoise" to automatically cache the results


getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(book) {
# Careful not to let just any name slip in here; a
# malicious user could manipulate this value.

text <- book    
myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))

myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
          control = list(minWordLength = 1))

m = as.matrix(myDTM)

sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: Você precisa alterar a função `getTermMatrix` para que ela faça alguma coisa com os objetos `coletor1` e `coletor2` dependendo de algum argumento dela.

Comment: Tente sempre dar à comunidade um  código que seja reproduzível. O que queremos dizer com reproduzível? Que possamos copiar e colar (`crtl` + `c` e `crtl` + `v` mesmo) seu código em nosso computador e teremos o mesmo problema que você tem. Caso você não faça isso, não teremos sequer como te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código tem muitos problemas. Segue abaixo uma solução genérica para o problema que você descreveu na pergunta: interatividade da núvem de palavras.

Como você não relatou nenhum problema com a leitura dos dados isolei as funções do `RPostgreSQL` e criei "livros fantasia". Tudo que você precisará fazer fazer é trocar o objeto `books` por algo como `books <<- list(coletor1, coletor2)`.

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

books <- list(Forzza = c("Um", "monte", "de", "palavras"),
              Viana = c("Outro", "texto", "vai", "aqui", "palavras"))

getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(text) {
  myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))

  myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
                             control = list(minWordLength = 1))

  m = as.matrix(myDTM)

  sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
})

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    terms <- reactive({
      input$update
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
          getTermMatrix(books[[input$selection]])
        })
      })
    })

    wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      v <- terms()
      wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
                    min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
                    colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
    })
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Word Cloud"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("selection", "Choose a book:",
                  choices = c("Forzza","Viana")),
      actionButton("update", "Change"),
      hr(),
      sliderInput("freq",
                  "Minimum Frequency:",
                  min = 1,  max = 1000, value = 1),
      sliderInput("max",
                  "Maximum Number of Words:",
                  min = 1,  max = 100,  value = 100)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))

      )
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Cara, eu te agradeço muito mesmo. Você não tem ideia de como me ajudou.Estou no ultimo ano da faculdade, perto de apresentar meu TCC, e o shiny era o ultimo detalhe que faltava para eu terminar.Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Sobre os problemas do código, realmente ha muitos, porque tentei adaptar de um outro código para esse. Realmente ha um  problema de leitura, que no meu caso precisava dele ler cada palavra sendo um campo(linha) da tabela que esta nas variáveis coletor1 e coletor2, pois ele não estava enxergando nomes compostos, apenas palavra por palavra. Mas o principal você já me ajudou. Mas esse ultimo problema eu posso  tentar resolver aqui.

Mas Valeu mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Te sugiro fazer outra pergunta isolando o problema que você está tendo com a leitura dos dados. Dá uma olhada neste [artigo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r). Queremos te ajudar, mas temos que ter como.